# Where do I go after obtaining the Phantom Cloak?

Tags: metroid-dread

I just obtained the Phantom Cloak after defeating the first boss in *Metroid Dread*, but I can't figure out where I'm supposed to go next. I can pass through sensor doors now, which has led me to an elevator to Catarsis, but that path seems to be surrounded by lava. Every other path I can think of on the map seems to be a Morph Ball passage too, which I don't have access to yet. Where do I go after obtaining the Phantom Cloak?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Illusory wall ahead**

As you exit the elevator in Catarsis, shoot the wall to your left instead of going through the obvious looking door on your right. The door goes to lava, the wall goes towards the next E.M.M.I. zone.

Comment: I think there are only two moments where it isn't obvious where to go next as there's no markers on the map on what blocks an area or what the next destination is. This is one of em, the other being after you get the Space Jump.

Comment: @JeffMercado Hmm I just got to the area after Catarsis, and while it's somewhat obvious you need to go there since you can't go back, you again have to find the hidden destructible block...

Comment: @kutschkem at least with this one, it's easy to accidentally discover it. There is a single completely blocked off path in the new area. If you happen to be shooting when you go back to the elevator, you'll find these blocks. Come to think of it, Dairon does the same thing as well, but the hidden blocks are at the end of the path. Could also say the same for Burenia.